# Markov order/number of lags in transfer entropy

Tags: markov-process, entropy

This paper:

[Measuring Information Transfer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/nlin/0001042.pdf)

introduced the transfer entropy, a measure which is able to distinguish driving and responding elements
and to detect asymmetry in the coupling of subsystems. It consider two systems that may be approximated by stationary Markov processes of order $k$ and $l$ respectively. In the paper I read that the most natural choices is $l = k$. Why? Intuitevely, I think that Markov order/number of lags should be identical for both time series to facilitate interpretation of results.

Can someone give me a more precise answer to this question?

Comment: " Intuitevely, I think that Markov order/number of lags should be identical for both time series to facilitate interpretation of results." I agree with you, but isn't it precisely what the choice $l=k$ implies?